# Bigquery caching when hitting table would provide a different result?

Tags: google-bigquery

As part of our Bigquery solution we have a cron job which checks the latest table created in a dataset and will create more if this table is out of date.This check is done with the following query

`SELECT table_id FROM [dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__] WHERE table_id LIKE 'table_root%' ORDER BY creation_time DESC LIMIT 1`

Our integration tests have recently been throwing errors because this query is hitting Bigquery's internal cache even though running the query against the underlying table would provide a different result. This caching also occurs if I run this query in the web interface from Google cloud console.

If I specify for the query not to cache using the

```
queryRequest.setUseQueryCache(false)
```

flag in the code then the tests pass correctly.

My understanding was that Bigquery automatic caching would not occur if running the query against the underlying table would provide a different result. Am I incorrect in this assumption in which case when does it occur or is this a bug?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in BigQuery. BQ should not cache when the query results will differ. I'll file a bug internally and investigate.

Comment: Thanks if it helps we first noticed the tests throwing errors on the 18th of January.

Comment: The bug has been identified, and should be fixed in public BigQuery in ~1 week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer for your question is: you are doing conceptually wrong. You always need to set the no cache param if you want no cache data. Even on the web UI there are options you need to use. The default is to use the cached version.

But, fundamentally you need to change the process and use the recent features:
**Automatic table creation using template tables**

A common usage pattern for streaming data into BigQuery is to split a logical table into many smaller tables, either for creating smaller sets of data (e.g., by date or by user ID) or for scalability (e.g., streaming more than the current limit of 100,000 rows per second). To split a table into many smaller tables without adding complex client-side code, use the BigQuery template tables feature to let BigQuery create the tables for you.

To use a template table via the BigQuery API, add a templateSuffix parameter to your insertAll request

By using a template table, you avoid the overhead of creating each table individually and specifying the schema for each table. You need only create a single template, and supply different suffixes so that BigQuery can create the new tables for you. BigQuery places the tables in the same project and dataset. Templates also make it easier to update the schema because you need only update the template table.

Tables created via template tables are usually available within a few seconds.

This way you don't need to have a cron, as it will automatically create the missing tables.

Read more here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#template-tables

Comment: Thanks for the answer I didn't know about template tables, sounds like a much better way of doing it.

Comment: note: template tables are available only for streaming scenario